# Product Invoice To Product Author -Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello WordPress Techies,

I have different author posting listing on my website (Not Product of Woocommerce) But a custom CPT I created with the help of JetEngine

But the checkout process passes through WooCommerce checkout but I would like the Listing Author to also get Order Invoice once order has been placed on their product or maybe a message that "They have a New Order Available" + The Woocommerce Invoice Details of User Who Purchased It. Excluding The User Mail and Phone Number

Please I'm not techy and would appreciate if a code can be provided